# Reverse searching(ctrl+r) in linux terminal

Tags: linux, shortcut

I now can only select the last history command that matches.

How can I select,for example, the last but two command that matches?

Answer (score 7):

Pushing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> repeatedly will find earlier matches.

Comment: Oh,never know this before!BTW, how can I switch to last but 1 from last but 2?

Comment: Switch to... what?

Comment: Switch to commands that has turned up before the current one, **reversed** `ctrl r` ?

Comment: You mean after? Ctrl-S does the opposite operation according to the man page, but terminals use Ctrl-S for flow control.

Comment: Yes.I just tried Ctrl-S,but seems no effect..

Comment: `ctrl-s` stops the terminal by default (at least on most of my systems), and `ctrl-q` will resume the session. i tried it just now, with `ctrl-r` first, and it still stopped the session. very cool about `ctrl-r` though, +1

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
# allow ctrl-S for history navigation (with ctrl-R)
stty -ixon
```

You can enter that command at a prompt if you just want to try it out.